# was careful to straighten / carefully straightened

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Could you please explain what's the difference in their meaning/emphasis?

> **He was careful to straighten** his room before leaving.
>
> **He carefully straightened** his room before leaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one means that he tidied the room carefully (with care).

The first means that he made sure that he remembered to tidy the room.